# How I can display an image in magento pdf in invoice ?

Tags: invoice, pdf

This is my code:

```
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("http://stefan.local/media/catalog/product/1/1.jpg");
$page->drawImage($image, 10, 30, 20, 50);
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:45:"Cannot create image resource. File not found.";i:1;s:1336:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\stefan\lib\Zend\Pdf\Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('http://stefan.l...')
Can someone help me with this ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass path like "C:\xampp\htdocs\stefan\media\catalog\product\1\1.jpg". not http path.

Comment: I still get this message, but if i write it like this: $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/stefan/media/catalog/product/1/1.jpg"); it works

Comment: Can you tell me why ?

Comment: because you have to pass full path.you can use: "Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.'1'.DS.'1.jpg'" instead of "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/stefan/media/catalog/prod‌​uct/1/1.jpg"

Comment: it works, can you tell me also what represents the params from drawImage ?

Comment: and one more question, why the image is reversed ?

Comment: see here http://www.creare.co.uk/tips-for-modifying-magento-pdfs